# Difference in the extracted address using jupyter notebook and .py script?

Tags: python

I have a pdf document containing text and US addresses. I am extracting its text using python library and then applying the pyap library to extract the address from text. I am getting the results when I ran the code using jupyter notebook but when I ran the same code using .py script I am not getting any results?

Comment: This can happen for many different reasons.  For example, you may be running the script from different working directory, your runtime environment can be different from the one you use on jupyter.  You need to post reproducible code snippet for people to help point out your problem.

Comment: @KotaMori I am using the same directory to run both jupyter notebook and .py script and also environment is same for both.